# GridViewItem from GridView

Tags: win-universal-app

In UWP (or WinRt) how can I get in code behind a GridViewItem from a GridView?
I tried

```
this.AppsGridView.ContainerFromItem(this.AppsGridView.Items[0]);
```

and it returns null. What else can I try? Also, is there a simple way to enumerate through all the GridViewItem object in a GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this, and it should works.

Code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<GridView x:Name="GridView">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding}" Background="Blue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>

<Button Background="Red" Content="GetItems" Click="OnGetItemsClick"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    GridView.ItemsSource = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

private void OnGetItemsClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = GridView.Items[0];
    var itemContainer = GridView.ContainerFromItem(item);
}
```

And this code works well when you define items manually :)